# std::unordered_map and duplicate keys

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, unordered-map

I'm using an stl unordered_map, and I can't seem to get the count method to work.
This is my program:

```
typedef unordered_map<char, int> Mymap;
int main() 
{
    Mymap m;  

    m.insert(Mymap::value_type('a', 1)); 
    m.insert(Mymap::value_type('b', 2)); 
    m.insert(Mymap::value_type('c', 3)); 
    m.insert(Mymap::value_type('b', 4)); 
    m.insert(Mymap::value_type('b', 5)); 

    cout << m.count('b') << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

The documentation for unordered_map says that `unordered_map::count(const Key& k)` returns the number of elements with the key `k`.
So I would expect the output here to be `3`, whereas the real output is `1`. Why?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An `unordered_map` maintains a 1:1 mapping of key to value, so `count` will always return zero or one.

You need an `unordered_multimap` if you want to map multiple values to a single key.

Comment: That's odd. Why does that function exist then? If you use it to check if a key exists in the map, why not just use the traditional way, `find(...) != end()`?

Comment: Indeed - the name `count()` is misleading. `exists()` would be better.

Comment: `count()` is part of the interface for all associative containers.

Comment: @Paul Manta: `map` is a [unique associative container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueAssociativeContainer.html) so `m.count()` returns either 0 or 1. But for an associative container in general such as multiset, multimap it can return values greater than 1.

Answer (score 14):

```
// g++ -std=c++0x init-unorderedmap.cc && ./a.out
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace {
  typedef std::unordered_map<char, int> Mymap;
}

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  Mymap m{ {'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {'b', 4}, {'b', 5}};
  cout << m.count('b') << endl;

  unordered_multimap<char, int> mm{ {'b', 4}, {'b', 5}};
  cout << mm.count('b') << endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
1
2
```